# How to write HashCode and equals function against mock function

Tags: java

Suppose there is a class ProductSet, which contains id, and Map.

```
public class ProductSet {
    private Long id;
    private Map<Long, Product> productsMap;
    // ...., including getter and setter, constructor function
}
```

Now, if in the mock testing class, if follow testing functions run successful, how to write the equals and hashcode function?

```
@Test
public void testMockingClassWithoutNameEquals() {
    ProductSet p1 = mock(ProductSet.class);
    ProductSet p2 = mock(ProductSet.class);
    assertEquals(p1, p2);
}

@Test
public void testMockingClassWithoutNameEquals() {
    ProductSet p1 = mock(ProductSet.class, "name1");
    ProductSet p2 = mock(ProductSet.class, "name2");
    assertNotEquals(p1, p2);
}
```

Comment: Why on earth do you mock `ProductSet` if you want to test `equals()` and `hashcode()` of `ProductSet`? Mocking `ProductSet` means that during the test no methods of `ProductSet` are executed - the mocks just return whatever you told them to return.

Comment: The thing is, I don't know what it means also, but this is the interview testing, it is not exactly the same, but finally it needs to solve what I want to say. Be honestly, before today, I even don't know there is a method mock(class, name) @ThomasKläger